# Настройка файла log4j для каждого потока отдельно

Tags: java, log4j

Есть такой файл `properties`:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, CA
#, FA

log4j.logger.searchLogger.quartz=OFF
log4j.logger.org.quartz=OFF

# Console appender configuration
log4j.appender.CA=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CA.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CA.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}%5p [%F->%M->%L]: %m%n

# File appender configuration
#log4j.appender.FA=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
#log4j.appender.FA.File=D:/log/application.log
#log4j.appender.FA.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
#log4j.appender.FA.layout.ConversionPattern=%r [%t] %5p (%F:%L) - %m%n
```

В проекте есть функционал при котором запускается отдельный поток и в нём выполняются действия. Как настроить `log4j` что бы на каждый такой потом он создавал свой лог файл и писал туда?

Comment: Возможно эта [ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1172113/how-do-i-setup-log4j-properties-so-that-each-thread-outputs-to-its-own-log-file#1172113) поможет.

Comment: @Владимир а почему не хотите оформить ответом?